# Pagination function doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Despite following exactly [the example in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link), the page I arrive at when clicking the pagination `next` link (http://localhost:3000/my_project/news/page/2/) doesn't exist ("page not found").

Why?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; echo 'paged = ' . $paged;
$regular_posts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);
while ($regular_posts->have_posts()): $regular_posts->the_post(); 
  the_title();
endwhile;
echo get_next_posts_link('Older Entries', $regular_posts->max_num_pages);
```

This code is contained in my "home.php" template, managing the "News" page which I created in dashboard and set as "Posts page" in "Reading Settings".

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a static home page or an archive page? (It looks like an archive page, but I just want to confirm). It its an archive page, if it for posts or custom posts?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that. This code belongs to the "home.php" template, managing the "News" page which I created in dashboard and set as "Posts page" in "Reading Settings". It's for regular WP posts.

Answer (score 1):

A static homepage is slightly different from an archive, as it `page` parameter instead of `paged`.

The [Codex Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page) page includes this code for static homepages, which will actually work in all cases (i.e. even archive pages) because its checking for both parameters:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }
```

But if you only need it to work on the homepage, Changing your code for the $paged variable to the following should work too:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Comment: Actually I realize http://localhost:3000/my_project/news/page/2/ gives "page not found", that's why it didn't display anything. http://localhost:3000/my_project/news/ is my posts page. I still get "page not found" when using your code, any idea what to try next?

Comment: @drake035 Are you using a custom post type with the "news" slug? If not, are you using a page & custom template to display the posts under the "news" page?

Comment: Yes I'm using a WP page entitled "News" (a regular WP page created in dashboard), and this WP page is set as "Posts page" in "Reading Settings".

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in function.php file,

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4) {
$showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;

global $paged;
if (empty($paged))
    $paged = 1;

if ($pages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if (!$pages) {
        $pages = 1;
    }
}

if (1 != $pages) {
    echo "<div class=\"fl-w-left main-pagination\">";
    if ($paged > 2 && $paged > $range + 1 && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link(1) . "'>&laquo; First</a>";
    if ($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . "'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {

        if (1 != $pages && (!($i >= $paged + $range + 1 || $i <= $paged - $range - 1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
            echo ($paged == $i) ? "<li class=\"active\">" . $i . "</li>" : "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "<a href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . "\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
    if ($paged < $pages - 1 && $paged + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($pages) . "'>Last &raquo;</a>";
    echo "</div>\n";
}}
```

Also, put this code in your page or post template file,

```
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) { ?>
                    <?php pagination($post_query->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php }
                ?>
```

Comment: The WordPress core already has a pagination helper `paginate_links()` and as a 404 is being returned for page 2, the page or post template file wont be executed, `404.php` will

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$wp_query->posts_per_page` in the template with a new instance of `WP_Query` doesn't work because the requested page number has already been validated against `$wp_query->max_num_pages` by WordPress before the template is executed. As the requested page is more than this value for the main query, the `404.php`  template is served instead, and your code in the `home.php`  template isn't even executed.

The trick is to get `$wp_query->max_num_pages` to match the true maximum number of pages by manipulating the main query to use your custom arguments, before the main query is performed. `$wp_query->posts_per_page` and `$wp_query->found_posts` will then match your results, resulting in a `$wp_query->max_num_pages` that does too.

The best way, in my opinion, is to edit the main query arguments before the main query gets its posts. For example, you could add the following to your theme's functions.php:

```
function custom_main_query($query){
  if(is_admin()) return;
  if(!$query->is_main_query()) return;
  if(is_home()) $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_main_query');
```

This will then mean a standard loop will work out the box too:

```
// Standard loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  the_title();
endwhile;

// Navigation links
previous_posts_link('Newer Entries');
next_posts_link('Older Entries');
```

If you are only manipulating the number of posts per page, it may be better to change the default posts per page by going to `Options => Reading` in WordPress admin and setting `Blog pages show at most` to 3 here instead.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs due to limits set on the number of posts to show on your templates. It's possible this is set to less than 4. So get to your WordPress dashboard and navigate to `Settings->Reading`. Look for **Blog pages show at most** and if the value is less than 4, increase it to the total number of posts to show on your template, plus the pagination link (in your case, this should be at least 4).