# Cannot get posts to display on previous_posts_link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just trying to get my posts to display on the front page on a WordPress site I am working on with some custom styling and custom fields.

I can get them to display fine on one page with them all displaying but as soon as I try to get paging working it doesn't work.

When I click the view previous posts button it changes the URL but loads in the same posts as the homepage.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

                <?php
                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=20&cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
                    ?>
                <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
                    <div class="grid-item">
                        <div class="basicgallerywithdesc">
                            <img src="<?php echo the_field('main_post_image') ?>" alt="Offer Image">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="spacer"></div>
                            <div class="clickheredeal"><span><h2>More Info</h2></span></div>
                            <div class="clickherefav"><span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>



</div>


                    <div class="movingposts"><?php
                next_posts_link( '<img src="wp-content/themes/SaleTree/img/arrowright.png"/>', $the_query->max_num_pages );
                previous_posts_link( '<img src="wp-content/themes/SaleTree/img/arrowleft.png"/>' );?></div>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
                <?php else:  ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If you are on a static home page, use `get_query_var( 'page' )` instead of `get_query_var( 'paged' )`, i.e. `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;`
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469514/pagination-function-doesnt-work-in-wordpress/46471057#46471057

Comment: Glad to help! Its an easy mistake, in every other case its `paged`, its only on a static homepage that you use `page`.