# WordPress Pagination Issue, displaying first page only

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have searched through the forms and can't find a solution that is working. I have this exact code on another site and it works. Not sure why it's not working here.

All it's doing is ever showing the first page of posts, and never shows a "newer" posts link (prev vs next button)

My posts section:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postItem">
            <div class="postItemInner flexContainer">
                <div class="postImage" style="background:url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)"></div>
                <div class="postInfo">
                    <div class="postMeta"><?php the_date('F d, Y g:i a'); ?></div>
                    <h2 class="postTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="postExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <div class="postReadMore"><a class="readMoreText" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE <img class="imgAlign" src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/icon_arrow_blue.png" /></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
} 
?>
```

And then my pagination section:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages, 
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),  
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 1,
            'mid_size'     => 2,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '<div class="newerBlog blogArrowBox"><img class="imgAlign" src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/icon_arrow_blue.png" /> Newer Posts</div>', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '<div class="olderBlog blogArrowBox">Older Posts <img class="imgAlign" src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/icon_arrow_blue.png" /></div>', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you using this code? e.g. is it on the homepage, your blog page or some other page?

Comment: @FluffyKitten it is on the homepage.

Comment: The homepage can use `page` instead of `paged` depending on whether it’s a static home page or not. Take a look at [this answer I wrote for someone else’s homepage pagination issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471057/514878) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: So this worked to paginate the results (thank you!), however now the issue I'm having is that the pagination links at the bottom always show the "next_text" link. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Do you mean that it shows it even though there are no more posts, or do you want it to show just the first 2 posts without any links to the other others?

Comment: It always shows even if are there no more posts. Also it never shows the "previous_text" link. I can show you the URL if I can send it privately.